# Error occurs when \usetikzlibrary in l3 style class file

Tags: errors, expl3, tikzlibrary

I have a class file which is simplified as follows:

```
% mwe.cls
\ProvidesExplClass{mwe}{2023/05/29}{0.1}{class file for writing mathematical exercises}

\LoadClass{report}

\RequirePackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
```

and I test it with `mwe.tex`

```
\documentclass{mwe}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

If I comment out the `\usetikzlibrary{intersections}` in `.cls` file, there is no error. Otherwise, an error occurs. To solve this problem, I found that `\ExplSyntaxOff` should be placed before the `\usetikzlibrary{intersections}`.

How to explain this phenomenon?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks for noting this! Are there some documentations about the matters that l3 class file writers should notice? `interface3.pdf` doesn't mention that point you have said.

Comment: @Stephen there is a feature request for tikz to make the library loader safe in such a context: https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/issues/1213